# How to check Number of rows or query which have extra spaces in between words from a table (oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanted to know how to check Number of rows or query return which have extra spaces(more than 1 spaces) in between words from a table. for example:

table: xyz

```
      column
row1) aa (spaces)    eeed    
row2) aksa  (spaces) dddd (spaces) eeed (spaces)   ddd     dddd
row3) abc kkomkdi
row4) xyz
```

I want the query result count as 2 or

```
row1) aa     eeed    
row2) aksa   dddd  eeed    ddd     dddd
```

thank you
Tom.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of ways to do this - length/replace, charindex etc, however simplest is probably just using [`LIKE`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/like.php):

```
select * from xyz where column like '%  %'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
select * from xyz
where CHARINDEX('  ',column) > 0
```

To get the count:

```
select count(column) from xyz
where CHARINDEX('  ',column) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from xyz where length(col_name) - length(replace(col_name, ' ')) > 1;
```